# Acelerar la velocidad de pronunciación de la voz de Google Translator

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python3: Las voces de Google me parecen un poco lentas, ¿Se puede modificar la velocidad con algún parámetro? hacer que el sonido descargado sea más corto:

```
from gtts

import gTTS

import pyglet

from pydub import AudioSegment

def tts(text, nombre_wav, lang):

        file = gTTS(text = text, lang = lang)

        filename = text+".mp3"

        file.save(filename)


tts("Hello World", text,lang="en")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La API que permite cambiar la velocidad es la del [servicio TTS de google](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/basics), que es una API que requiere registro y [es de pago](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/pricing)

En cambio el módulo `gTTS` que estás usando usa una API no documentada relacionada con el servicio "Google Translate". Esa API también puede pronunciar cosas, pero no está pensada como servicio TTS por lo que no permite textos muy largos, ni cambiar la velocidad, salvo entre el valor "normal" (que es el que has oido) y el "lento", que va a 1/3 de la velocidad.

De hecho la API translate está pensada para ser usada por la página web de [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/?hl=es), y no por aplicaciones de terceros. Usarla como hace `gTTS` puede ser considerado "abuso" por Google, quien te puede bloquear la IP si nota muchas peticiones desde tu sitio.

Comment: He estado mirando los ejemplos de google TTS

https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python

pero no veo ningún parámetro para modificar la velocidad ¿estás seguro que se puede?

Comment: @NombreApellido La documentación que tienes que mirar es [esta](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/texttospeech/index.html). Está bastante farragoso, pero el método [synthetize_speech()](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/texttospeech/gapic/v1/api.html#google.cloud.texttospeech_v1.TextToSpeechClient.synthesize_speech) lleva como parámetro un objeto de tipo  [AudioConfig](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/texttospeech/gapic/v1/types.html#google.cloud.texttospeech_v1.types.AudioConfig) el cual tiene la opción `speaking_rate`.